# Enterprise Library Security Block

Tags: security, enterprise-library

Does anyone know if there is a way to create the security configuration section via the Enterprise Library API or do we have to use the config wizard / edit by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure any section via the new fluent interface.
Just use ConfigurationSourceBuilder. Like so:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureSecurity()
       .AuthorizeUsingRuleProviderNamed("MyRules")
         .SpecifyRule("Rule1", "MyRuleExpression")
       .CacheSecurityInCacheStoreNamed("SecCache")
         .WithOptions
           .UseSharedCacheManager("MyCacheManager")
           .SetAsDefault();

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

You even get IntelliSense support.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28PandP.50%29.aspx)